# Preencher um listview com as propriedades de uma classe em delphi

Tags: delphi

Estou fazendo uma aplicação MVC em delphi, estava indo tudo bem, quando chegou na parte de listar as informações em uma listview, me deparei com um pequeno problema, como à aplicação está dividida em camadas, fiz o laço de repetição na camada controller, qnd fui recuperar as informações para a view, só retornou a última informação da consulta, ao invés de trazer todos os registros, a minha dúvida é essa, como faço para exibir todas as informações na camada view:

Na camada controller no método pesquisa:

```
function TControlEstado.Pesquisar(Pcodigo: string): TControlEstado;
var I : Integer;
begin
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Close;
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Clear;
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('select est00_codigo      ');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_descri      ');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_uf          ');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_dtCadastro  ');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_status      ');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('from cadest00');
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('where est00_descri like ' + QuotedStr('%'+Pcodigo +'%'));
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Open;

  if Fcontrole.SqlGeral.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Pcodigo:='';
    ResultadoQuery := 0;
  end;
    ResultadoQuery := 1;
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.First;
  for I := 0 to Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Count -1 do
  begin
    while not Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Eof  do
    begin
     Self.est00_codigo         := Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_codigo')      .AsInteger  ;
     Self.est00_descri         := Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_descri')      .AsString   ;
     Self.est00_uf             := Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_uf')          .AsString   ;
     Self.est00_dtCadastro     := Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_dtCadastro')  .AsDateTime ;
     Self.est00_status         := Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_status')      .AsInteger  ;
     Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Next;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

No meu formulário principal criei um método que instancia a conexão e a classe `TConttolEstado`:

```
procedure TFrmEstado.Inicialize;
begin
  LcEstoque;                                     //Método que define propriedades host de conexão
  Conectar := TMControlador  .Create;            //Cria a conexão com os parâmetros definidos anteriormente
  Estado   := TControlEstado .Create(Conectar);  // Instância do obejto da classe Estado

end;
```

//Aqui eu uso a recuperação das informações :

```
procedure TFrmEstado.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if validaPesquisa then
  begin
    lvGrid.Items.Clear;
    Estado.Pesquisar(edtValor.Text) ;
    if ResultadoQuery = 1 then
    begin
        listItem := lvGrid.Items.Add;
        listItem.Caption:=(IntToStr(Estado.est00_codigo));
        listItem.SubItems.Add(Estado.est00_descri);
        listItem.SubItems.Add(Estado.est00_uf);
        listItem.SubItems.Add(DateToStr(Estado.est00_dtCadastro));
        if Estado.est00_status = 0 then
           listItem.SubItems.Add('Inativo')
        else
        if Estado.est00_status = 1 then
           listItem.SubItems.Add('Ativo');
    end
    else
       MsnAlerta('Erro', 'Vazio');

   lvGrid.Items[0].Selected := True;
  end;
  AjustaForm;
end;
```

Aqui vai a resolução:

Na camada View ficou assim:

```
procedure TFrmEstado.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  if validaPesquisa then
  begin
    lvGrid.Items.Clear;
    Estado.Pesquisar(edtValor.Text, lvGrid) ;
    if ResultadoQuery = 0 then
             MsnAlerta('Erro', 'Vazio')
    else
    begin
      lvGrid.Items[0].Selected := True;
//      Exibir(mImpimir);
    end;
  end;
  AjustaForm;
end;
```

No controller ficou assim:

```
function TControlEstado.Pesquisar(Pcodigo: string; Lista: TListView): TControlEstado;
   var I : Integer;
  begin
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Close;
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Clear;
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('select est00_codigo      ');
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_descri      ');
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_uf          ');
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('      ,est00_pais        ');
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('from cadest00');
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Add('where est00_descri like ' + QuotedStr('%'+Pcodigo +'%'));
  Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Open;

  if Fcontrole.SqlGeral.IsEmpty then
  begin
    Pcodigo:='';
    ResultadoQuery := 0;
  end
  else
    ResultadoQuery := 1;
    Fcontrole.SqlGeral.First;
  for I := 0 to Fcontrole.SqlGeral.SQL.Count -1 do
  begin
    while not Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Eof  do
    begin
     listaEstado :=Lista.Items.Add;
     listaEstado .Caption   :=(IntToStr(Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_codigo').AsInteger));
     listaEstado .SubItems  .Add(Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_descri').AsString);
     listaEstado .SubItems  .Add(Fcontrole.SqlGeral.FieldByName('est00_uf').AsString);
     Fcontrole.SqlGeral.Next;
    end;
  end;
```

end;

Desculpe a demora da resposta...

Comment: Pelo que eu pude observar, você percorre todos os estados e para no último, mas como você não percorre novamente para jogar no ListView, por isso ele preenche o ListView com o último, porque você não passa o ListView como parâmetro na função pesquisar e manipula o componente dentro da função assim não precisa se preocupar em percorrer de novo.

Comment: Boa idéia, vou fazer isso!

Comment: Pensando bem, acho que isso fugiria a lógica de separação de camadas... Pq a função faz parte do meu controller... Vc poderia fazer um  exemplo de como ficaria...

Comment: Valeu Marco Giovanni, funcionou que uma maravilha!

Comment: conseguiu fazer?

Comment: Consegui Sim! \o/

Comment: @AlexDeSousa, pode postar como fica a resposta?

Comment: Desculpe a demora da resposta:
Aqui ficou o Form View:
procedure TFrmEstado.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  if validaPesquisa then
  begin
    lvGrid.Items.Clear;
    Estado.Pesquisar(edtValor.Text, lvGrid) ;
    if ResultadoQuery = 0 then
             MsnAlerta('Erro', 'Vazio')
    else
    begin
      lvGrid.Items[0].Selected := True;
//      Exibir(mImpimir);
    end;
  end;
  AjustaForm;
end;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que eu pude observar, você percorre todos os estados e para no último, mas como você não percorre novamente para jogar no ListView, por isso ele preenche o ListView com o último, porque você não passa o ListView como parâmetro na função pesquisar e manipula o componente dentro da função assim não precisa se preocupar em percorrer de novo.

Alex, se minha resposta conseguiu resolver o seu problema, poderias aceita-la, assim ajudaria os outros membros do forum. Abraços!